# Selenium/Python Finding Element and Clicking it

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been researching for a while about this and here is the code I wrote

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
time.sleep(10)
get("some website")
time.sleep(10)
x = driver.find_element_by_id("vB_Editor_QR_textarea")
x.click()
```

It keeps giving me error the part it's not working is getting the `find_element` and `click()`

It keeps giving me error from `webdriver.py`

here is the screen shot of the error note: i don't have a mouse at the moment so i just took a pic

https://gyazo.com/bc6f8d3e77f2e9d9b5bcbfe202b73258

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Please post the error stack here.

Comment: this is the error im getting note: i don't have a mouse so i just took a screenshot https://gyazo.com/bc6f8d3e77f2e9d9b5bcbfe202b73258

Comment: Please post the text of the error. At some point in the future the image will be gone and this question will be less valuable. You also need to post the HTML you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://example.com") # Make sure you use double quotes
```

And instead of `time.sleep()` you should use [implicit and explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#waits). I usually use an implicit wait.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # 10 seconds
```

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.

Comment: so the rest of the code looks fine to you? i will try it once i get home

Comment: Also, don't use `time.sleep()`. Use implicit and explicit waits. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple google search automation:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class AutoTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_auto_test(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.google.com")
        element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#lst-ib')
        element.send_keys("StackOverflow")
        element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sblsbb > button > span').click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```